# SAS proc transpose

Tags: sas, transpose, proc

I have the following dataset

```
Account 1       Account 2       Account1Amount    Account2Amount 
A.              B.              25.               55
F.              D.              10.               70
```

I get the following when I transpose by Account 1 and Account 2

```
      Amount 1.        Amount 2.        Col1
           25.                    55.                   A
           25.                    55.                   B
           10.                    70.                   F
           10.                    70.                   D
```

But I want the following

```
    Amount 1.        Amount 2.        Col1
           25.                    0                      A
           0.                     55.                   B
           10.                    0                      F
           0.                      70.                   D
```

In other words, I don't want the amounts to be double counted for each account since it messes up my true total across different accounts. This is also a sample of the data, I actually have 185 rows.

I just don't know how to go about solving this. Is there an option is proc transpose that I can use, or perhaps do the transpose and then fix the issue. But I just can't wrap my head around going about solving this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you creating three variables instead of just two, Account and Amount?

Answer (score 0):

The original data set is what I would consider atypical.  It appears to contain two parallel sets of information without any explicit key.

```
data have;
input
Account_1 $     Account_2 $     Account1Amount    Account2Amount; datalines;
A.              B.              25.               55
F.              D.              10.               70
run;
```

The stated result appears to be from this transpose:

```
proc transpose data=have out=got;
  by account_1 account_2;
  var account1amount account2amount;
run;
```

Transposing the parallel data as stated is probably easiest using a data step arrays and output statements.  Going with only `transpose` would involve two transposes and `set` stacking the outputs.

```
data want_stated;
  set have;
  array accounts account_1 account_2;
  array amounts account1amount account2amount;
  array amount amount1 amount2;

  col1 = accounts(1);
  amount(1) = amounts(1);
  amount(2) = 0 ;

  output;

  col1 = accounts(2);
  amount(1) = 0;
  amount(2) = amounts(2);

  output;
run;
```

A more use useful normal categorical transposed form is probably the account/amount vector (as mentioned by Tom)

```
data want_maybe;
  set have;
  array accounts account_1 account_2;
  array amounts account1amount account2amount;
  group = _n_;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(accounts);
    account = accounts(_n_);
    amount = amounts(_n_);
    output;
  end;
  keep group account amount;
run;
```

Comment: Hi Richard, This works great. I have one additional question. What if i have another column of let's say countries...How would i make sure that those countries then correctly correspond with the correct account if I were to use the array syntax?

Comment: @user2916331  If you have some type of ID variable, like COUNTRY, then include that in the `KEEP` statement.  Having an ID variable probably means there is no need to generate the `GROUP` variable this code is adding.

Comment: Follow Tom's advice.  If you have continuing issues, please create a new question that states the data `have`, the desired output `want`, any code you have tried along with error or warning messages shown in the log -- if you need, read up on asking questions for `[sas]` https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sas/info.

Answer (score 0):

one more way, if you have few columns is to

```
   proc sql;
   select Account_1,  Account1Amount, 0  from 
   have 
   union
   select Account_2, 0, Account2Amount from 
   have b;
```